# Xlsxwriter insert_image URL option not hyperlinking locally

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

I'm downloading images from an URL, saving them locally, then inserting them in the excel file. I've been able to successfully add the website URL to the image with the method options. I've also been able to manually hyperlink the image to the actual jpg file, so the default picture viewer opens the original, not resized image.

Nevertheless I can't get this last step to work with the library. This is the process:

```
    # Paths
    image_file_path = os.path.join(image_folder_name, image_name)
    image_absolute_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), image_file_path)
    print(image_file_path)
    print(image_absolute_path)

    download_image(full_url, image_file_path)
    # Save as JPG format to remove constraints
    image_size = save_image(image_file_path, width, height)
    resize_scale = get_resized_scales(image_size, (width, height))
    options = {'x_scale': resize_scale[0],
               'y_scale': resize_scale[1],
               'x_offset': 7,
               'y_offset': 7,
               'object_position': 1,
               'url': image_absolute_path
               }
    worksheet.insert_image(row_index, 4, image_file_path, options)
```

Printing both paths outputs:

```
images\image.jpg
C:\Users\Me\IdeaProjects\Downloader\images\image.jpg
```

I've tried both in the 'url' section and the hyperlink is just not there.

Python version 3.8.0

xlxswriter 1.2.6

Windows 10 OS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local hyperlinks in XlsxWriter need to be prefixed with `'external:'` (see the [write_url()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url) docs for a full explanation of XlxsWriter URL handling).

So in your case the following should work:

```py
options = {'x_scale': resize_scale[0],
           'y_scale': resize_scale[1],
           'x_offset': 7,
           'y_offset': 7,
           'object_position': 1,
           'url': 'external:' + image_absolute_path}
```

Comment: Ah dammit I saw that in the docs, I just thought it was only for other xlxs files as per the examples... Thanks a lot, sorry for the silly question.